# Power automate trigger condition on new record created on a SharePoint list

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to create a power automate workflow on new item being added to SharePoint list. Now I need an email sent when a new item is added to the list **AND**  column name manager ( matches any of the set of values ( which could be like 50 users) I know I could use the trigger condition but how can I make the trigger condition regex use a set of value.

manager in ( 'John','Mary','Eric'.......etc)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this trigger condition will work for you ...

```
@greater(length(intersection(createArray(triggerBody()['Editor']['DisplayName']), createArray('John', 'Mary', 'Eric'))), 0)
```

Obviously, you can change the field that the trigger runs off but I picked the **Editor/DisplayName** field as it looked like the one that made the most sense.

Take note as well, it will look for full proper display names, it must match, it's not `regex` or `contains`, it's a perfect match.

Regex natively in PowerAutomate does not currently exist so this is your best bet I'd say.

Comment: @greater(length(intersection(createArray(triggerBody()['Editor']['DisplayName']), createArray('John', 'Mary', 'Eric'))), 0)  - does this go in the trigger condition? And the createarray content can be 50+ names how do I handle that?

Comment: Yep, it goes in the trigger condition and then just add all of your 50+ names.  See how it goes.  Again though, they need to be 100% in line, i.e. if the persons name is `Barry Crocker` then that's what you need to put in, `barry crocker` will not work.

Comment: @greater(length(intersection  - what are these functions exactly doing? Is  there an efficient way to create that array?

Comment: Nope, if you want it in the trigger, it has to be hardcoded. Otherwise, you need to drop into the flow itself and do the check there. Did you want to make that dynamic? Cos your question doesn’t state that.

Comment: Also, those expressions and what they do can be found here ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference